# Error al unir dos variables en un array

Tags: laravel

me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar a solucionar este problema, el cual tengo, ya que al unir dos tablas en una sola tuve que juntar dos marcas que pertenecían a un solo modelo, pero cada una tenia un ID diferente, entonces al tratar de hacer una consulta por medio de Laravel me surge un error que no puedo corregir, ya que me gustaría juntar las dos marcas y poder generar la consulta a la BD y que me traiga los modelos que pertenecen a esos ID.

Este es mi codigo:

```
 public function cargaModelo($id_marca){

 $marcas = Brand::where('idmarca', '=', $id_marca)->get();

         foreach ($marcas as $key) {

            $marca1  = $key->amarca;//id = 59
            $marca2  = $key->bmarca;//id = 64

            $nuevo_array = array($marca1,$marca2);

            $id_marca = explode(',',$nuevo_array);

            $modelos = Modelo::where('id_marca','=', $id_marca)->get();
             foreach ($modelos as $value) {

                $model = $value->nombre_modelo;

                echo $model;
             }
         } 
 }
```

El error que me marca es el siguiente:

explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Agradecería mucho por sus comentarios, saludos.

Comment: solo debes eliminar la `$id_marca = explode(',',$nuevo_array);` ya que tienes un arreglo.. debes hacer referencia a `$nuevo_array[0]` y a `$nuevo_array[1]` explode solo funciona con strings, y si quieres que seleccione 2 ids solo debes ponen `IN` no `=` ejemplo `Modelo::whereIn('id_marca', $nuevo_array)->get();`

Comment: Hola @Bryro te agradezco por tu comentario, coloque tal cual como me mencionas y me funciono. Saludos